# Rails. stop database connection and reconnect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I try to implement a very easy backup process. Just dump the database into a file. The user gets all files displayed, choose one, and then the dump is loaded back. But loading back the dump is not possible while the rails server is running. How can I manage this? How can I stop the database connection, do my stuff and then reconnect to the database?

- I have tried with postgresql and rake commands to dump the database and recover it -> Permission denied
- I have tried with Sqlite3. Just copy the databasefile into a backup folder. But if I want to delete the current one to replace it with a new -> Permission denied
- I have tried with Sqlite3 dump. I dumped the database but again I can only load the dump back if the rails server is not running.

There are libraries out like Yamldb which works, but this library only can save one backup. I have to save more then one and give them names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need another app running for that.

Comment: Hm okay. Is there another way to create "save points" which can the user select from a menu IN the app?

Comment: you can use pg_dump (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html) to create the snapshot. You can record that in a database or read the dump files from the hard drive.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But how can I read this dump in again without shut down the rails server?

Comment: @Bolic I don't think you can. Reload a dump mea s that you will perform unrecoverable actions, and rails needs to restart to update the model. When you restart the rails server, rails evaluates / updates the model attributes present in the database.